# IE11 in webbrowser control does not work with attachEvent(), even in compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, wpf, wpf-controls, internet-explorer-11

In my WPF app, I host a website inside a webbrowser control. I have no control over the website. Since our IT department upgraded to IE11, the website stopped working inside IE11 as it uses the removed attachEvent() javascript method.

Now, putting the browser itself in compatibility mode fixes this when working directly in IE11. But when the website is opened within my application inside the browser control, it does not work, despite I have forced the control into compatibility mode (via FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry key). I checked that this setting was repsected and I tried every compatibility mode from IE7 to IE10 ... no luck.

I really don't understand why it works directly in IE11 when it is forced into compatibility mode, but not in the browser control.

What could be the issue here?